# How can I have smaller bottom using the translate css property?

Tags: css

I have a problem using the translate css function.

I have HTML as below.

```
<div class="outer-div">
  <img src="https://www.visioncritical.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/BLG_Andrew-G.-River-Sample_09.13.12.png"/>
  <div class="inner-div">
    Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum Loreum Ipsum

  </div>
</div>
```

You will notice that I have an outer div which has an image and an inner div with contents. I am pushing the inner div in negative y-axis by 40px using the translate CSS property. I am doing it using the sample css below:

```
.outer-div {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.inner-div {
  background-color: red;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  transform: translate(0, -40px);
}
```

However, by doing so, I now have a gap of 40px at the bottom of the div. I want to keep only 20px gap as shown in attached image.

[image]

How can I only have 20px at the bottom? I have also created a sample code-pen ( http://codepen.io/hellouniverse/pen/XNyzZX ) to show the issue

Comment: `transform: translate(0, -20px);` isn't an option because?

Comment: Same questions as @Roberrrt. Also another suggestion would to give the outer div a fixed `height: 444px` instead of `height: auto`.

Comment: @Robert, Firstly, no, it has to be -40px because of the way it is designed. I want the bottom blue portion to be 20px and not 40px;

Comment: @SUBHUMAN, No, I have given a height here as a sample. However, in reality, for me it is dynamic depending on the contents inside.

Comment: And we're not allowed to restructure stuff?

Comment: If possible,... using only css ? The thing is this is a sample from a dynamic system I am building.. The structure comes from a lot of complex backend system...

Comment: the goal is you need increase height of red div or decrease height of blue div?

Comment: The goal is I need to move the red div up (without using any position absolute) and also ensure the blue div below is only 20px and not 40px;

Comment: Can you better explain, beside _of the way it is designed_, what is the purpose to move it upwards? ...to hide a part of the image? ...or? ... There might be more proper ways if we know why

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Answer (score 1):

try this css:

```
.outer-div {
  background-color: blue;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 445px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.inner-div {
  background-color: red;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  transform: translate(0, -40px);
}
```

Comment: I can not provide a pre-defined height to the div since the contents inside are dynamic and can grow or decrease.

Answer (score 0):

use this transform property to make 20px to 40px:

```
transform: scaleY(2);
```

the scaleY specifies the height and the (2) multiplies the given height "20px" to 40px.

Comment: Did you just doubled everything? That was not what I wanted

Comment: that because your outer div class is wrapping all your elements. You should make a separate div just for the blue box and it should work